# Defining LaTeX parentheses delimiters thing for meow-mode

Tags: latex

## Setup

In the spirit of [evil-tex](https://github.com/iyefrat/evil-tex), I'm trying to define a `thing` for the `meow` [modal editor](https://github.com/meow-edit/meow) that demarcates LaTeX parentheses delimiters such as `\left( \right)`, `\langle \rangle`, `( )`, `\bigl( \bigr)`. I am aware that evil-tex has support for such things, so I lifted some configuration and attempted to adapt it for meow:

```
;; Defines master list of LaTeX parentheses delimiters
(require 'cl-lib)
(setq latex-modified-delim-pairs (cl-loop for (l r)
            in '(( "\\langle" "\\rangle" )
                 ( "\\lvert" "\\rvert" )
                 ( "\\lVert" "\\rVert" )
                 ( "(" ")" )
                 ( "[" "]" )
                 ( "\\{" "\\}" ))
            nconc (cl-loop for (pre-l pre-r)
                     in '(( "\\left"  "\\right")
                          ( "\\bigl"  "\\bigr")  ("\\big"  "\\big")
                          ( "\\biggl" "\\biggr") ("\\bigg" "\\bigg")
                          ( "\\Bigl"  "\\Bigr")  ("\\Big"  "\\Big")
                          ( "\\Biggl" "\\Biggr") ("\\Bigg" "\\Bigg")
                          ( "" "" ))
                     collect (list (concat pre-l l) (concat pre-r r)))))

;; Left-side delimiters
(setq latex-left-math-parens (mapcar #'car latex-modified-delim-pairs))
;; Right-side delimiters
(setq latex-right-math-parens (mapcar #'cadr latex-modified-delim-pairs))

;; Register delimiters as new thing 
(meow-thing-register 'latex-delim
                     `(pair ,latex-left-math-parens ,latex-right-math-parens)
                     `(pair ,latex-left-math-parens ,latex-right-math-parens))
(add-to-list meow-char-thing-table '(?D . latex-delim))
```

This configuration works well for `meow-inner-of-thing`. The issue with `meow-bounds-of-thing` is that meow matches eagerly. e.g. if `|` denotes the point, and we have a situation like

```
\left( some text | \right)
```

running `meow-bounds-of-thing` marks only `( some text \right)`, when I want it to mark the whole sample text.

## The Issue

The issue is the presence of both `(` and `\left(` in the master list, and similar situations occur for `\left\langle`, `\left[`, `\left\{`, etc. Because meow is eagerly looking for matches, the left side matches only the occurrence of `(`, but I'd like to match the "largest" possible string in the master list, which in this case would be `\left( \right)`.

## Possible Solution/Question

One possible solution would be to just remove the `(`, `\langle`, `[`, `\{` from the master list entirely and rely on other meow things (like `round`, `square`, etc), but I'd **strongly** prefer to keep all possible LaTeX parentheses delimiters under the same char in the `meow-thing-char-table`. I don't think this is an acceptable compromise.

**How can I modify the thing definition/meow matching behavior to achieve this generality?**

The meow code relevant to matching things is located [here](https://github.com/meow-edit/meow/blob/master/meow-thing.el).

Answer (score 0):

After taking some time to think about it and learn a little elisp, I have a solution:

```
;; Constructs cons cell of match with distance to point
(defun append-bounds-distance (pair)
     (if pair
      (cons pair (min (-  (point) (car pair))  (- (cdr pair) (point))))
    'nil))

;; Finds match with minimum distance to point
(defun find-min-distance-match (matches-with-distances)
  (let ((nearest-match (cons (point) (point)))
        (min-distance (float 1.0e+INF)))
    (dolist (match matches-with-distances)
      (when (cdr match)
        (when  (> min-distance (cdr match) )
          (setq nearest-match (car match))
          (setq min-distance (cdr match)))))
    nearest-match))

(defun my/meow-latex-paren-search (near)
  "Find LaTeX parenthesis bounds.
NEAR denotes if match should be inner or bounds"
  (interactive)
  (let ((found-pairs (list )))
    (dolist (leftright meow--latex-delim-pairs)
      (push  (meow--thing-pair-function
              (car leftright) (cdr leftright) near) found-pairs))
    (let ((bounds-with-distances (mapcar #'append-bounds-distance found-pairs)))
      (find-min-distance-match bounds-with-distances))))
    
(defun my/meow-latex-paren-bounds ()
  (my/meow-latex-paren-search nil))

(defun my/meow-latex-paren-inner ()
  (my/meow-latex-paren-search t))
```

The logic is we look through the whole master list and search for delimiters around the point, regardless if one has been found or not. Then we find the match that is nearest to the point, returning.

We then wrap this function to include the `near` argument to denote if we want to match the `inner` of the thing or the `bounds` of the thing. The last two functions may be passed to `(meow-register-thing)` as logic to match the inner and bounds of thing.